# rails persist objects over requests in development mode

Tags: ruby, object, request

I am trying to interact with Matlab.Application.Single win32ole objects in my rails application. The problem I am running into is that while I am developing my application, each separate request reloads my win32ole objects so I loose the connection to my matlab orignal instances and new instances are made. Is there a way to persist live objects between requests in rails? or is there a way to reconnect to my Matlab.Application.Single instances?

In production mode I use module variables to store my connection between requests, but in development mode Module variables are reloaded every request.

here is a snippet of my code

```
require 'win32ole'

module Calculator
  @engine2 = nil
  @engine3 = nil

  def self.engine2
    if @engine2.nil?
      @engine2 = WIN32OLE.new("Matlab.Application.Single")
      @engine2.execute("run('setup_path.m')")
    end
    @engine2
  end

  def self.engine3
    if @engine3.nil?
      @engine3 = WIN32OLE.new("Matlab.Application.Single")
      @engine3.execute("run('setup_path.m')")
    end
    @engine3
  end

  def self.load_CT_image(file)
    Calculator.engine2.execute("spm_image('Init','#{file}')")
  end

  def self.load_MR_image(file)
    Calculator.engine3.execute("spm_image('Init','#{file}')")
  end
end
```

I am then able to use my code in my controllers like this:

```
Calculator.load_CT_image('Post_Incident_CT.hdr')
Calculator.load_MR_image('Post_Incident_MRI.hdr')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep an app-wide object in a constant that won't be reset for every request. Add this to a new file in  `config/initializers/`:

```
ENGINE_2 = WIN32OLE.new("Matlab.Application.Single")
```

You might also need to include the `.execute("run('setup_path.m')")` line here as well (I'm not familiar with WIN32OLE). You can then assign that object to your instance variables in your `Calculator` module (just replace the `WIN32OLE.new("Matlab.Application.Single")` call with `ENGINE_2`, or simply refer to them directly.

I know this is beyond the scope of your question, but you have a lot of duplicated code here, and you might want to think about creating a class or module to manage your Matlab instances -- spinning up new ones as needed, and shutting down old ones that are no longer in use.

Comment: Thank you very much, I am trying to vote up your answer, but I need to gain a few more reputation points first. Will come back and give you the credit due when I have those. Thanks again.